# Error Connecting to a JMS Topic Broker via SSL using Net::STOMP::Client module in Perl

Tags: perl, ssl, jms, stomp

I am trying to connect to a TIBCO JMS Topic Broker with the help of Net::STOMP::Client package in perl.

I am using the SSL approach while creating a new Net::STOMP::Client Object and passing the attributes 'uri' & 'sockopts' where it takes the Topic Uri & SSL Certificate files for Authentication.

When I try to run this script it throws an error saying : -

**cannot SSL connect to mmx-nprd1-06:7222: IO::Socket::INET6 configuration failed**

Code is give below :-

```
use Net::Stomp;
use Net::STOMP::Client;

use Moose;
use strict;
use warnings;
use FindBin qw($Bin);

print "\n$Bin\n";

my $stomp; 

  $stomp = Net::STOMP::Client->new(
      uri => "stomp+ssl://mmx-nprd1-06:7222",
      sockopts => {
          # path of the directory containing trusted certificates
          SSL_ca_path   => "$Bin/JmsCertificate/",
          # client certificate to present
          SSL_cert_file => "$Bin/JmsCertificate/aix_jms_cert.pem",
          # # client private key
          SSL_key_file  => "$Bin/JmsCertificate/aix_jms_key.pem",
          # passphrase of the client private key
          SSL_passwd_cb => sub { return("password") },
      },
  );

  $stomp->connect();

  my $peer = $stomp->peer();
  printf("connected to broker %s (IP %s), port %d\n", $peer->host(), $peer->addr(), $peer->port());

  my $sid = $stomp->uuid();
  $stomp->subscribe(
      destination => "/queue/test",
      # we use the generated subscription id
      id          => $sid,
      # we want a receipt on our SUBSCRIBE frame
      receipt     => $stomp->uuid(),
  );
  my $count = 0;
  my $frame;

  while ($count < 10) {
      $frame = $stomp->wait_for_frames(timeout => 1);
      if ($frame) {
          if ($frame->command() eq "MESSAGE") {
              $count++;
              printf("received message %d with id %s\n",
                     $count, $frame->header("message-id"));
          } else {
              # this will catch the RECEIPT frame
              printf("%s frame received\n", $frame->command());
          }
      } else {
          print("waiting for messages...\n");
      }
  }
  $stomp->unsubscribe(id => $sid);
  $stomp->disconnect();
```

Can Someone help me out with this as I am not able to figure out whats going wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

I also had some issues using the uri key try the following :

```
$stomp = Net::STOMP::Client->new(host => "mmx-nprd1-06", port => 7222,
  sockopts => {
      # path of the directory containing trusted certificates
      SSL_ca_path   => "$Bin/JmsCertificate/",
      # client certificate to present
      SSL_cert_file => "$Bin/JmsCertificate/aix_jms_cert.pem",
      # # client private key
      SSL_key_file  => "$Bin/JmsCertificate/aix_jms_key.pem",
      # passphrase of the client private key
      SSL_passwd_cb => sub { return("password") }, # Leave this out if your key doesn't require a passphrase
  },
);

$stomp->connect(login => "aix_jms", passcode => "some_password");
```